# Printing same label but changing one value in each

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to print the label below multiple times. Is there any way to create a VBA button capable of printing the same label whilst incrementing the (CTN NO:) value?

Thanks For Helping!

[image: Excel Label]

Comment: mineflamer, how many copies are you printing of each single, un-incremented label? You can attach some code to a `Workbook_BeforePrint` Event and use Static variable for CtnNo.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/static-statement

Comment: @klausnrooster at the moment I only plan on trying to get one copy of each first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(In a regular or even Sheet Module). Want a new button? Insert a Form Controls Button, or a TextBox and assign this macro to it. Macro rolls Ctn back to 1 after printing Ctn 12. Guessed at cell addresses. No idea what Sheet/Tab name is.

```
Option Explicit

Sub PrintIncrementingCtn()
    dim pgi as long
    Static Ctn As Long    '? C10 / of E10?

    For pgi = Range("C10?").Value to Range("E10?").Value
        If Ctn = 0 _
        Or Ctn > ThisWorkbook.Sheets("?").Range("E10?").Value Then
            Ctn = 1
        End If
    
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("?").Range("C10?").Value = Ctn
        ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintOut Copies:=1, Collate:=True
        Ctn = Ctn + 1
    next pgi
End Sub
```

Comment: @mineflamer, I changed my answer to better match your question. Please note `Ctn` in sub does not refer to your cell. It stands on it's own except for resetting to 1 based on your total Cartons cell. You can remove that part if you want.

Comment: doesn't this mean that I would have to print each one individually for it to be incremented? Is there any way for it to be printed from 1-12 as a set? Course my usual method would be to increment by myself each time after I print the previous ctn.

Comment: mineflamer, yes, that is correct. So I changed the answer. Button will now print as many pages as Total Ctns has, eg: 12 if started at 1. But you can set Ctn manually to any number less or equal to (eg) 12 and it will do the right thing. It increments only after printing. If you manually start at 6 it will print 6 through (eg) 12.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your help was very much appreciated! Still have lots of the project left to do but will try it myself first before getting some more help.  Might come back to this question if there are any other issues. :)